# Backing up drives - alternating drives with Backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I know how you can use Backup (the gui for duplicity) to back up to an external hard drive.  But what if you want to back up to multiple drives?

The situation might be you want to back up to drive A, and put it offsite, and then back up another drive "B" for daily backups.

Will this confuse the Backup program, or does it base the backup on information stored with the backup itself?

I would think offsite backup plus a local backup gives you the capability to handle the worst case scenario and the more likely "destroyed important files due to user error" scenario with some flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

@[asylumax](https://askubuntu.com/users/680536/asylumax) Using `duplicity` from command-line you can make many backups as you want in different drives. The issue is when time to time you move arround your local info and try to perform future backups to the same remote backup destiny. Note that duplicity allows you to integrate those backups using the following flag: `--allow-source-mismatch`

Before anything, check your duplicity version and read the corresponding manual, they have nice documentation.

Click on [duplicity website](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/) and search your manual.

Suggestion: test it with a copied random folder with files.

Hope this can helps!